# To give zoom effect to my add marker in android?

Tags: android

In my Google map am using one marker which should use for save location and always point the current location.When i finish add my location it should be in the drop down list when click the location it should add marker with zoom effect.I want to know how to give zoom effect to my new add marker location.

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if( mListener != null )
    {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        //Move the camera to the user's location and zoom in!
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 12.0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: but initially it have to be in current location

Comment: am new to android.could u say me what is mListener.for what i have to create object as mListener?

Comment: i m just giving u an idea so you use this code on ur onclick listener (drop down click)